# MvcContrib Grid - Issue binding to dynamic values in a Dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I have a collection of SearchResult objects which contain a Dictionary of any number of dynamic attributes, such as Name, Address, Food Preference, or anything else. I want to dynamically create columns (based on a Columns collection) and display the attributes in the MvcContrib Grid.

```
@Html.Grid(Model.SearchResults).Columns(column =>
{
    foreach (var col in Model.Columns)
    {
        column.For(sr => sr.GetAttribute(col.Name)).Named(col.Title);
    }
})
```

The issue I'm having is that each row in the Grid is completely filled with only the last attribute, as such:

```
Name           Address       Telephone
____________________________________________
01496 555555   01496 555555  01496 555555 
01496 444444   01496 444444  01496 444444
01496 111111   01496 111111  01496 111111
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: It's not clear how your models look like. Please post their structure.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question...

It was an "access to modified closure" issue. The column variable needs to be assigned to a local variable within the foreach loop, as so:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.SearchResults).Columns(column =>
{
    foreach (var col in Model.Columns)
    {
        var localCol = col;
        column.For(sr => sr.GetAttribute(localCol.Name)).Named(localCol.Title);
    }
})
```

Comment: could you show how your `Model.SearchResults` and `Model.Columns` objects look like?

Comment: I no longer have that code as changed it to use WebGrid (which proved easier for server side paging if I remember correctly). The Columns collection is List<Column>, where Column is a pretty standard class with basic properties for Name and Title.